# "Don't escalate your close votes with flags"?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

I recently reviewed an answer on SO, and flagged it as "not an answer". The action was declined, with a comment of "please don't escalate your close votes with flags". I don't have enough reputation to vote to close questions. So what does this mean?

[image]

Comment: link/screenshot please? This looks like a mod mistake

Comment: [Question where answer was flagged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265882/parse-time-vs-execution-time)

Comment: I can't see any answer worth flagging there. I can see one answer there (I'm 10k+), and it looks pretty much like an answer to me. As far as I can tell, this should have been rejected.

Comment: The answer shown is not the one I flagged. That answer has been removed.

Comment: So you flagged it as "very low quality" instead?

Comment: umm... the screenshot says "very low quality [on the question]", not "not an answer"

Comment: I flagged a different answer than currently shown on that question as "Not an Asnwer", it was something along the lines of "this worked for me too".

Comment: I can't see any deleted answers there, and I should be able to.

Comment: That's strange then. `jeb`'s answer was not the one I flagged, I'm sure of it.

Comment: @ArmanH: there are no other answers, and that flag you got a screenshot of is a VLQ flag, not Not an answer.

Comment: it looks like the answer has evaporated, and the flag shifted to the question. Do you have any evidence you flagged something else than the screenshot says you did?

Comment: @Mat, I see. Still confused about the "don't escalate your close votes" part.

Comment: Either you flagged something else than you thought you did (happens...) or you made a flag on something that didn't exist and the system registered a different flag (then it's a [tag:bug])

Comment: Are you sure you didn't just flag the question as "very low quality"?

Comment: @Bart, at this point I'm not so sure. I was rather confident I flagged an answer as "Not an answer", but I could be wrong. This was several days ago.

Comment: Perhaps the moderator thought you had the vote-to-close privilege? If he did, it screams "BUG" to me.

Comment: Whether I do have vote-to-close privilege or not, if I haven't voted to close the question, why should the flag be declined (unless it's an inappropriate flag)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That message was not intended for you. Someone else had flagged and also voted to close. Those flags can not be dismissed independently, so the decline message was meant for the other person, not you.

(I'm not the mod who declined, for the record)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that flags are not dismissed independently.

Comment: I think it's time to escalate the issue of not being able to dismiss flags individually ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak But please don't use flags for that.